# How to clear the edittext when onclick on Button

Tags: android, button, onclick, android-edittext

How do I clear the data which is given to an EditText dynamically when clicking the button?
How do I write the code? What function or method do I use?

Comment: so before enter any data i think you want to give some hint to user ??Is am i right?

Answer (score 24):

Try

```
 public void clear(View v) {
     edittext.setText("");
 }
```

Where `clear` is registered as onclick handler for the button in the layout file like this

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/ClearButton"
        android:text="@string/ClearButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="clear"           <<<--------here
        android:src="@drawable/clear"
    />
```

Answer (score 11):

```
Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        EditText et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
        et.setText("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use function

```
myEditText.setText("");
```

Answer (score 3):

Its simple, I'm just considering that u know how to create the XML file... I'm putting across the java part of it....

```
public class StackOverFlow extends Activity{

    Button buttonToClick;
    EditText editTextToclear;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    buttonToClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            editTextToclear.setText("");


        }
    });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Register an OnClickListener for the button which deletes the text in the EditText. This document describes how to do that: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

To clear the text in the listener just set an empty text: yourButton.setText("");

Answer (score 2):

if your button name is : rstBtn

& edittext field name is  :name

then insert an Onclick Event handler :

```
rstBtn.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {          
public void onClick(View v){
            name.setText("");
        }
    });
```